# How to use SaveOnServerPath Rotativa in MVC core c#?

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-core-mvc, rotativa

I want `ViewAsPdf` use to Save file on Server Path but not work in MVC core

**My Code**

```
var pdfname = String.Format("{0}.pdf", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
var path = Path.Combine(@"MyPathProject\wwwroot\doc\Claim\Request", pdfname);
path = Path.GetFullPath(path);
var pdfResult = new ViewAsPdf
{
     ViewName = "_ToPDF",
     Model = memo,
     FileName = pdfname,
     SaveOnServerPath = path
};
```

### Startup.cs

**Configure Function**

```
...
RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env.WebRootPath);
...
```

> My code have not any error but file not saved

Comment: You likely need to use IWebHostEnvironment to get the file provider and/or ContentRootPath to build a valid file path relative to the application

Comment: can you explain by code ?

Answer (score 1):

If you used asp.net core 3.0 or later, you could try to inject the `IWebHostEnvironment` into the controller class and then you could use `IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath` to get current web root path "wwwrot".

More details ,you could refer to below test demo

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    private IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment environment) {
        _hostingEnvironment = environment;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {
          var path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, @"doc\Claim\Request\Sample.pdf");
        return View();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Only for explain use static **Path** use your way but not Save file PDF

Comment: Could you please post the details action codes? Besides, have you configured Rotativa. AspNetCore settings in the startup.cs class?

Comment: Update my quotation